# Why is $(N,N' G)$ reaction not listed?

Tags: nuclear-physics

If I go here,

http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/#

go to the **by Nuclide** tab, check the "Reaction" box, and search for $\rm^{24}Mg$ in the **Nuclide** box; various reactions which produce $\rm^{24}Mg$ appear. Included is the $\rm^{24}Mg(N,N'G)$ reaction *(Neutron is incident on $\rm^{24}Mg$ Nucleus, Neutron and Gamma are emitted)*.

If I do the same search but with $\rm^{26}Mg$ instead of $\rm^{24}Mg$, the $\rm^{26}Mg(N,N'G)$ reaction is not listed.

Basically for some **Nuclides** this reaction is listed and for others it is not. I'm assuming that the reason for this is that this reaction is not allowed/doesn't occur.

- My question is why this reaction is permitted for some isotopes but not others?

Comment: A different way of thinking about it is, some reactions were _measured_ for some isotopes but not others. To investigate further, you can either follow the references listed on the NNDC site, or go to the various sources of nuclear data sheets for a summary of the experiment (which is spotty at best, sadly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not (necessarily) a question of what's permitted so much as what's been measured, and published, and entered into the ENDF database.  The reference for the 24Mg paper is

- 1984EL12,
  Nucl.Instrum.Methods 228, 62 (1984),
  D.Elenkov, D.Lefterov, G.Toumbev,
  "Two-Target DSAM following the (n, n'γ) Reaction with Fast Reactor Neutrons"

and the abstract specifically mentions 24Mg; you'd have to find the paper to see whether they used an isotopically purified sample or whether they just selected against data from the 20% of magnesium with extra neutrons.

At the top of the search results is a link steering you to the XUNDL (experimental, un-evaluated data), which contains this reference for data on both (n,$\gamma$) and (n,n) on all stable magnesiums:

- 2012MA14,
  Phys.Rev. C 85, 044615 (2012),
  C.Massimi, for the n_TOF Collaboration,
  "Resonance neutron-capture cross sections of stable magnesium isotopes and their astrophysical implications"

  NUCLEAR REACTIONS 24,25,26Mg(n, γ), E=1 eV-1 MeV; measured Eγ, E(n), time-of-flight, capture yields, σ(E), resonance parameters using n_TOF facility at CERN. 25,26,27Mg; deduced resonances, levels, J, π, neutron and gamma widths, Maxwellian averaged cross sections. R-matrix analysis. Comparison with KADoNiS database. Discussed impact on s-process abundances and neutron resonance contribution to 22Ne(α, n)25Mg reaction.

Happy hunting!